# Find code that could be reached by a specific function

Tags: c++, c, analysis

I have a hard time formulating this question. The reason I'm asking is that I want to convert some C++ code with emscripten to java script code, but I don't think I need to convert the whole code base.

Is it possible in C++ to find all the code that a particular function could reach into when executed? Then I would know which part of the code I need to convert and which one I can just ignore.

Comment: It's called "call hierarchy" and can be shown by common IDEs

Comment: @Lundin I believe a static analyzer will be sufficient here, unless there are code paths which are implemented for impossible inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "call hierarchy" as Eugene said. You can use automatic documentation tools to get this information.

I strongly recommend you to try doxygen because it is really easy to use:
http://www.doxygen.nl/